# How to declare a 2 dimension int [ , ] in Typescript

Tags: typescript

Hello I wonder what would be the equivalent of int [ , ] in typescript.

number[ , ] does not work. 
Note that I cant use a matrix [ ] [ ]

Thank you for helping.

Comment: Javascript has no such feature.

Comment: JS doesn't support multidimensional arrays, therefore TS can't either.  It does support nested arrays if you want to go that route instead.

Comment: I have an API that receives a variable as int [ , ] how would I make it compatible?

Comment: Your question makes no sense; no such API can exist in Javascript because no such feature exists in Javascript.

Comment: Its an API in C# .cs file

Comment: Your question still makes no sense; you cannot directly call C# from JS/TS.  Are you actually sending an AJAX request? What format does it accept?

Answer (score 2):

Javascript, and therefore Typescript, doesn't have multidimensional arrays, but you can work around it by nesting arrays inside of another array. The following will create a 10 x 10 matrix with values initialized to 0:

```
var f = new Array();

for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    f[i] = new Array();
    for (j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
         f[i][j] = 0;
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

Upon re-reading your question it almost sounds like you want something like a tuple.
In tht case you basically just want an array of x amount of int:

```
var tuple = [1, 3, ...]
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to use an array of arrays (`[][]`) because JavaScript does not have any built-in multi-dimensional array object.